# Yahoo Sending PM Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, perl, yahoo

I want to write a PHP code (or other code like perl ...) that send a yahoo PM to my friend . 
may you help me in algorithm , about how to connect to yahoo server , how to send the pm ...
Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo's developer site](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/) should be a good start. For example, a [PHP library for Yahoo Mail](https://github.com/michaelcurtis/ymailphp) is linked there.

> With the Mail API, you can build applications that display message
>   summary information, parse message contents, manage folders, and even
>   compose and send messages.
>
> Client libraries in Python, PHP and VB.NET are available to make using
>   the Mail developer service easier.

This could be a good start to do something similar with the [Yahoo Messenger API](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/).

More searching reveals the [Yahoo Messenger PHP SDK](https://github.com/yahoo/messenger-sdk-php) and [libpurple](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpurple/), a library for IM access.

Comment: perl before bovines.... (pun intended). +1 for an answer that the Q didn't deserve.